# Verify that overloaded method was called with the right arguments from overloading method

Tags: java, mockito

I want to write Mockito tests for the following class:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public String doSomething(SomeObject a, JsonArray b) {
        doSomething(a, b, "");
    }

    public String doSomething(SomeObject a, JsonArray b, String c) {
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

I kind of wanted to mimick default arguments by overloading the method `doSomething`. The second `doSomething` I already got a Test Case for that is verifying, that the stuff in there is working correctly.

Now I want to test the first `doSomething` by just verifying, that the call to the second in there is called with the correct arguments.

So my try for the testcase was:

```
@Test
public void testDoSomething() {
    // Prepare
    final SomeClass clsIns = Mockito.mock(SomeClass.class);
    final SomeObject someObj = Mockito.mock(SomeObject.class);
    final JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();

    // Act
    clsIns.doSomething(someObj, jsonArray);

    // Assert
    Mockito.verify(clsIns).doSomething(someObj, jsonArray, "");
}
```

But this is not verifying the call to the second overloaded method but instead telling me, that the arguments were different (Wanted: `someObj, jsonArray, ""`, Actual: `someObj, jsonArray`)

How can I tell Mockito, to check the arguments of the overloaded (second `doSomething)` method?

Comment: Is your overloaded perhaps final?

Comment: No, both are public and not final.

Comment: You're mocking the whole class. So you're also mocking the first method, not just the second one. Read the mockito documentation and look for spies and partial mocks.

Comment: That test makes no sense to me. If `doSomething(SomeObject, SomeObject)` calls the overloaded method or not doesn't matter to the test. The tested class is a black box and implementation details are unimportant. The only thing that should matter to the test is: does the method behave correctly with the given arguments, i.e. is the result correct (return result or whatever). How it got to that result is no concern for the unit test.